# How do I use the boolean equals(object o) method and call the object the method is applied to?

Tags: java, object, methods, boolean, equals

This is what my method at the moment looks like:

```
//this method should check if the pokemon are equal//

  public boolean equals(Pokemon other){
  boolean equality;
  if (**XXXXX** == other)
     equality = true;
  else
     equality = false;
  return equality;


   }
```

So this is supposed to compare two objects, but my question is how do I call the object that the method is being applied to? For instance, the main code should apply this equals method to Pokemon a, which looks like:

```
 if (a.equals(other))
     System.out.println("Pokemon are equal!");
```

How do I input or call "a" (the object the method is applied to) into my method so that it compares them to be equal? Because when I replace **XXXXX** in the code to look like:

```
 if (Pokemon == other)
     equality = true;
```

I get the error:

```
Pokemon.java:130: error: cannot find symbol
  if ( Pokemon == other)
       ^
  symbol:   variable Pokemon
  location: class Pokemon
```

Comment: You also need to override `hashCode()`.

Comment: What's the point of overriding `equals()` if what you are doing is `==` comparison? And BTW, you are not overriding `equals` at all. The method should have `Object` as parameter type.

Comment: The whole body of your `equals` method can be replaced by `return **XXXXX** == other`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're calling `.equals()` on your object `a`, the method executes with `a` as its context, meaning the `this` keyword will refer to `a` inside of that method, just like any other method called on any other object.

Also, be careful with using `==`. That will see if the two references refer to the *same exact object in memory*. It is highly unlikely that this is only what you want. More likely you will want to check various member variables on the two Pokemon objects to see if *those* variables are equal, and then if they are return `true` to indicate the two Pokemon objects are indeed equal. The variables you choose are up to you and your criteria for what makes two Pokemon "equal".

Often, there will actually be a `==` check at the beginning of a `.equals()` implementation, because if it's true, then the method can return true immediately since the references are referring to the exact same object in memory. If the `==` is false, then you can continue checking member variables or whatever other criteria you have for computing equality.

Note also that you're *overloading* the `.equals()` method by giving its arguments signature a reference of type `Pokemon` instead of type `Object`.  If you want to truly *override* the base `Object.equals()` method, you'll want to do:

```
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    // Comparisons
}
```

You'll need to cast `other` to a `Pokemon` object (and use `instanceof`) if you want to use methods and member variables specific to the `Pokemon` class. You need this override if you want other JDK (or even your own) code that uses `.equals()` to call your custom `.equals()` method, instead of the base `Object.equals()` one.

Comment: The `==` check is often done as the first check in an `equals()` method. If it's true, then `equals()` can quickly return true.

Comment: Yes, what I meant to do is check if those variables are equal (not the same exact object in the memory). So at the moment while Pokemon a is "Pikachu 1" and Pokemon other is "Pikachu 1" it says they are not equal.

So do I split up the variables inside of Pokemon and compare those instead?

Comment: @user2908614 Your `Pokemon` class can likely remain the same. What you'll want to do in this method is check things like `if (this.name.equals(other.name)) { return true; }`. Assuming the `Pokemon` class has a `name` variable (guessing a `String`), then that line will see if the names of each Pokemon are equal. If so, the `.equals()` method will return `true`. You can add more conditional statements to the `if` statement if you want to check more variables. If you have an accessor/getter method for `name` (like `.getName()`), I'd use that instead of plain `.name`.

Comment: @user2908614 Great! Make sure to mark the answer that solved your problem, so that others coming to Stack Overflow with the same question can see that this is solved and hopefully benefit from it. I think new users have a brief blocking period before they can accept answers.

Answer (score 1):

You should override the equals method provided by Object within your Pokemon class like this:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o)
{
    // check if the "addresses" of o and this object are the same
    if (this == o)
        return true;
    // check if o is of instance Pokemon
    else if (o instanceof Pokemon)
    {
        // need to convert Object to Pokemon - it is save as we already know that
        // the o is actually a Pokemon instance
        Pokemon p = (Pokemon)o;
        // compare fields of o with fields of this instance
        if ((this.someField.equals(p.someField) 
            && (....))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here the equals method first checks if both objects refer to the same instance, if not it checks if o is of instance Pokemon and then compares every single field you need to identify if both objects are equal.

Note however, that this example is incomplete as I don't know what fields you have defined for your Pokemon class. When overriding equals() it is good practice to also override `public int hashCode()` - here you should include every field you compare in equals within your returning hashCode(). Further reading: http://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/why-always-override-hashcode-if-overriding-equals/20 http://www.javaranch.com/journal/2002/10/equalhash.html

Answer (score 0):

That's what the `this` keyword does.